# What does it mean that "a woman's egg dropped"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, non-standard-english

This context comes from the show "Euphoria"

"I was shooting dope before your mama's **egg dropped**."

My research:

1)**drop an egg** (Urban Dictionary definition)

To become aroused to the point that one spontaneously ovulates, regardless of time in one's menstrual cycle.

*That dude is so handsome. He makes me so horny I could drop an egg.*

Or maybe it's the ellipsis of this phrase:

2)**dropping more eggs then the easter bunny**

When a woman is having her period

*Did you hook up last night? No she was dropping more eggs then the Easter bunny*

?

Did he mean that "**he was shooting dope before her mama had her first period?**

Comment: Here it just means before you mother could get pregnant *as the egg has to travel down the fallopian tube and "drop" into the uterus* to meet the sperm or be reabsorbed. That is the meaning here.

Comment: Probably the egg that dropped (was ovulated) by the other person's mother was the one that was inseminated by the other person's father (and developed into the other person). Meaning 'I was shooting dope since before the beginning of your life'or 'since a very long time ago'. In Britain we might say 'I was shooting dope when you were still swimming in your dad's bollocks'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I was shooting dope before your mama's egg dropped" *could* mean *...before your mother had her first period (menstrual cycle)*. But most likely the intended sense is...

> *...before your mother "ovulated" the **specific** egg which would be fertilized and eventually grow into **you***.

It's just a more vivid / insulting alternative to *I was doing [whatever] **before you were born***. Much more evocative than just ***Your mama!*** for an insult.